# Which authentication method is good with Angular front end and .net core backend

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a angular 10 application( upgraded from angular 4) which is running as a front end and having .net core 3.1 web api (connecting to SQL server database)which is running as a back end project.

Now i am planning to implement login and authentication using both application. But confused with which technology i should follow?  have read so many technologies like [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction) , [Oauth](https://oauth.net/2/) (please point any others also there) or i should look for something like [OWIN](http://owin.org/) ?  Which is best in terms of security and performance?
And which is the best way to hash the passwords in database?

I know the topic and question needs large volume of consideration but just the guidance will be enough for me to proceed.

Please help me!

Comment: If you're using .net Core 3.1, why not use the authentication of .net Core? You should has an "API" that call to the functions necesary: this functions makes large use of `RoleManager` and `UserManager` -you need inject in the "controller"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to put things in perspective

- Owin is a way to communicate with your API in the .NET Framework, it has its way to implement OAuth2
- OAuth2 is a standard that tells you how to authenticate/authorize
- JWT is a tool that OAuth2 uses to authenticate (by validating the token)

You need to combine most of these technologies in to an implementation.

In layman terms:

- Upon successful login create a JWT token
- In the token you have an access token and a refresh token
- Refresh token is used to recreate an access token when it expires
- Access token is used to validate your identity

If you want to have an authentication server because you have a big system I suggest [IdentityServer](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: if we are using owin then also need to return JWT token? what all are other token types suites here?

Comment: To your first question yes. Alternatives to token types? Maybe only those that are outdated security wise